# Any sample async JAX-RS webhook example

Tags: rest, jax-rs, webhooks

I have a JAX-RS web service. 
One of the operations may take a long time so I need to make this an asynchronous REST call and then callback the client once it's complete.

I read about "WebHooks" and wonder is there a sample implementaion I can follow?
http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/07/AsynchronousRest